# Return char[] to used it in strtok() function

Tags: c

I have function

```
char *priq_pop(pri_queue q, int *pri)
{
    char *out;
    if (q->n == 1) return 0;

    q_elem_t *b = q->buf;

    out = b[1].data;
    if (pri) *pri = b[1].pri;

    /* pull last item to top, then down heap. */
    --q->n;

    int n = 1, m;
    while ((m = n * 2) < q->n) 
    {
        if (m + 1 < q->n && b[m].pri > b[m + 1].pri)
        {
            m++;
        }

        if (b[q->n].pri <= b[m].pri)
        {
            break;
        }
        b[n] = b[m];
        n = m;
    }

    b[n] = b[q->n];
    if (q->n < q->alloc / 2 && q->n >= 16)
    q->buf = realloc(q->buf, (q->alloc /= 2) * sizeof(b[0]));

    return (char *)out;
}
```

And I need to use returned value in `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    pri_queue qq = priq_new(0);
    char test[] = "test1,test2";
    char *ret;
    int pp;
    char *x;
    char *y;

    priq_push(qq, "test2", 2);
    priq_push(qq, "test,s", 0);

    ret = priq_pop(qq, &pp);
    printf("%s\n\n", ret);

    x = strtok(ret, ",");
    y = strtok(NULL, ",");

    printf("%s\n%s", x, y); 

    return 0;
}
```

But with this code, my program stop working, when it gets to `x = strtok(ret, ",");`. Error is in returned value (in `ret`), because if I use variable `test`, it's work. How can I fix my problem please?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: No need to cast the return value of `priq_pop`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth
I know, where the error is, but I don't know how to fix it. I start with C few days ago and I don't understand how work with pointers yet. I try to resolve this by myself, but program don't get any error, so I have no success.

Comment: OK. Teel me what is `pri`? Is that only a pointer declared in the `priq_pop` function?

Comment: @haccks It's a parameter to `priq_pop`, apparently used to store the priority of the item that's returned.

Comment: @Barmar;`if (pri) *pri = b[1].pri;` line is cofusing to me.

Comment: @haccks It means "If the `pri` pointer was supplied, store the priority of the returned element in the variable that it points to." `main()` supplies it with `&pp`.

Comment: @Barmar; It seems to me that `pri` is also a member of a structure (`b[1].pri`).

Comment: Of course. He's implementing a priority queue, it has to store the priorities.

Comment: @Barmar; OK. Now clear.

Comment: Also, do yourself a favour and do not use variable names like `pp`, `qq` and the like. It makes your code very hard to read, for others and yourself as well. The time invested by typing a bit more to make your variable names self explanatory does pay off in the long run. Just try reading code you wrote a year ago, and you'll know what I mean.

Comment: @cmaster
This code is just for test. I'll use this code (with a few modification) in another bigger application and then I'll rename variable and I'll add comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing constant string literals onto your queue here:

```
priq_push(qq, "test2", 2);
priq_push(qq, "test,s", 0);
```

`"test2"` and `"test,s"` are string literals, and you're pushing pointers to them onto your priority queue.  String literals are not writeable.

When you pop from your priority queue, you're getting back the same pointer you pushed, and then handing it to `strtok`.  `strtok` needs to modify the string it is passed.  But, because you're passing it a pointer to a string literal, it results in an exception.

You need to pass writeable strings to `strtok`.  That requires either making a copy before you push it onto the queue (and freeing it when you're done with it), or making a copy when you pop it off the queue (and, again, freeing it when you're done with it).

You can either use `strlen`, `malloc` and `strcpy` to make the writeable copies, or the commonly available (but nonstandard) `strdup`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like right fix to my problem :) 
But can you please give me a hint, how can I create a copy of string which I'm pushing to my queue?

Comment: If your environment has `strdup`, that's the easiest way:  `strdup(string)` will `malloc` memory and copy the string into it.  It's up to you to later `free` that memory.  Otherwise, this link shows one way to write your own `strdup`: http://vijayinterviewquestions.blogspot.com/2007/07/write-c-program-to-implement-your-own.html

Comment: So if I will have hundreds of elements in my queue, I must have array with copies of these elements, right?

Comment: The `strdup` function will allocate memory for each string with `malloc`.  You do not need to make a separate array to store these copies; they will get allocated on the heap.  The only thing you need to do is `free` them when you're done with them.  (That is, call `free()`, passing it a pointer to the copy of the string, when you're done with the string.)